# using select * in hql but getting the address of the value

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to get all the values from the database when a condition is met. But i am only getting the address of the list and not the values when column is ALL. I tried using `<c:forEach>` but i keep getting an error java.lang.String. For the other column it is working fine. so here is my code in jsp

```
c:url var="actionUrl" value="process" />
<form id="student-form" method="post" action="${actionUrl }">
<select name="column">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>lastName</option>
    <option>firstName</option>
    <option>cpNum</option>
    <option>birthday</option>
    <option>grade</option>
</select>&nbsp

<select name="condition">
    <option>=</option>
    <option><</option>
    <option>></option>
    <option><=</option>
    <option>>=</option>
    <option>!=</option>
</select>&nbsp

<select id="gradeID" name="grades">
</select>&nbsp

<button id=submit>Submit</button><br/><br/>
</form>

<p>${studentList}</p>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String process(@RequestParam(value="column", defaultValue="") String column,
        @RequestParam(value="condition", defaultValue="") String condition,
        @RequestParam(value="grades", defaultValue="") int grades, ModelMap model)
{
    model.addAttribute("studentList", studentDao.findData(column, condition, grades));
    return "StudentForm";
}
```

StudentDaoImpl

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Student> findData(String column, String condition, int grades)
{
    if(column.equals("All"))
    {
        String hql = "FROM Student x WHERE x.grade"+ condition +":grades";
        Query query = getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("grades", grades);
        List<Student> result = query.list();

        return result;
    }

    else
    {
        String hql = "SELECT x."+ column +" FROM Student x WHERE x.grade"+ condition +":grades";
        Query query = getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("grades", grades);
        List<Student> result = query.list();

        return (List<Student>)result;
    }
}
```

StudentDao

```
public interface StudentDao 
{
  public List<Student> findData(String column, String condition, int grades);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<c:foreach>` this way:

```
<c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student">
    Name: <c:out value="${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}" />
    <!-- More data -->
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: i don't know what happened but my forEach is working perfectly now thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

User iterator and keeping filling the pojos and adding them to the list.